# Google Chrome for Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, wine, cross-platform

Is there any way to use Google Chrome on Linux (specifically, Fedora 8)? Is there a native version for Linux, or would I have to use Wine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom Calloway has created a Chromium repository for Fedora 10, 11 and 12:

You can use it by creating a /etc/yum.repos.d/chromium.repo with the following contents:

```
[chromium]
name=Chromium Test Packages
baseurl=http://spot.fedorapeople.org/chromium/F$releasever/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Unfortunately, you say you're running Fedora 8 which doesn't help, but you really should considering upgrading.

```
From: "Jon Stanley" <jonstanley gmail com>
To: fedora-announce-list redhat com
Subject: FINAL REMINDER: Fedora 8 EOL
Date: Tue, 23 Dec 2008 13:55:40 -0500
This is a reminder that as of January 7, 2009, Fedora 8 will be
end-of-life and no further updates, including security updates, will
be released at that time, and new builds will not be allowed in the
buildsystem.

Also as of that date, all open bugs against Fedora 8 will be CLOSED WONTFIX.

Thanks!
-Jon
```

Reference: https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-announce-list/2008-December/msg00021.html

Answer (score 15):

You don't need Wine. There's a native Linux build of Google Chrome available @ http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Linux [Debian package only, for the time being ]

Comment: It's not much help for someone who's on Fedora 8.

Comment: @nagul fedora 8 was edited later.After this post.

Comment: The page I linked above states that you can extract the .deb file and try running it. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome 4.0 works reasonably well on Wine as per the WineHQ [appdb entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17588). That said, you can now use the official [Google Chrome for Linux](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Linux) version if you're on Ubuntu. If not, you can still use the [Crossover Chromium port](http://www.codeweavers.com/services/ports/chromium/) for linux which is available for a wider audience.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu you can use ppa :
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main

and see this manual :
[chrome-in-ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-chromium-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-using-deb-package.html)

Comment: I heard must release in deb package

Answer (score 1):

Checkout from git, and build:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/UsingGit